# s3 bucket logging in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am playing with this code in terraform to enable s3 bucket logging.
wondering what this optional parameter "target_prefix" TIA!

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket" {
bucket = "my-tf-log-bucket"
acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
    bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
    acl    = "private"

logging {
    target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.log_bucket.id
    target_prefix = "log/"
}
```

}

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why it is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html#server-log-keyname-format)

> (Optional) Assign a prefix to all Amazon S3 log object keys. The prefix **makes it simpler for you to locate the log objects**. For example, if you specify the prefix value logs/, each log object that Amazon S3 creates begins with the logs/ prefix in its key.

> The key prefix can also **help when you delete the logs**. For example, you can set a lifecycle configuration rule for Amazon S3 to delete objects with a specific key prefix.